# Find out PID of a process and how much memory it's using in Java / JVM?

Tags: java, neo4j, jvm

I have Neo4J running on my WebFaction shared server and I want to increase the heap available to it using

`$ java -XX:NewSize=128m -XX:MaxNewSize=128m -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -Xms512m -Xmx512m`

But how do I find out the current heap memory setting? Is there a command for that?

Thank you!

Comment: The current setting is in `conf/neo4j-wrapper.conf`

Answer (score 2):

To find proper process use:

`jps -lmv`

Then check heap settings using jmap:

`jmap -heap PID`

Here you have a lot of detailed information and max heap size is under key MaxHeapSize.

Please notice that you have to use tools from the same JDK which runs your neo4j instance. To find out which java is used by your application execute
`ls -l /proc/$PID/exe`

Also it's recommended to use the same user.

Comment: Thank you! I find the process ID using the first command, but when I use the second one I get this error again: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
 at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.runTool(JMap.java:196)
 at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.main(JMap.java:128)
`

Comment: Thank you! How do I check if there's a few java versions? `java -version` tells me there is 1.7.0 version installed.

Comment: The are two reasons on this. First is different JDK used and the second is different user. Please check if there are more than one java versions installed.

Comment: So I think it's only 1 java version, which means it's a different user. How do deal with that? Can I check which user is running Neo4J and then check the heap using that user?

Comment: Ok, the user that's running the process has the id of `971` - all the processes have the same id... and what can i do next? Thanks!

Comment: It has to be different java version. Please execute ` ls -l /proc/YOUR_PID/exe`. It will show directory of your java process. Then use `which jmap` and check if it's for sure the same jvm.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the memory particular PID is using by

```
top -PID <PID>
```

if you want to see the memory parameters passed originally to JVM you could use

```
jinfo <PID>
```

Comment: No, this latter jinfo doesn't work... I only see erros

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
 at sun.tools.jinfo.JInfo.runTool(JInfo.java:97)
 at sun.tools.jinfo.JInfo.main(JInfo.java:71)
Caused by: sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VMVersionMismatchException:

Comment: jinfo 32097
Attaching to process ID 32097, please wait...
Warning: the type "const char*" (declared in the remote VM in VMStructs::localHotSpotVMTypes) had its size declared as 8 twice. Continuing.

Comment: are you sure it is of same version as it the jvm?